# Free particle and harmonic oscillator coupled

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

I'm currently playing with a toy model given by the Lagrangian
$$L=\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}+\frac{m\dot{y}^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2+x y,$$
which is basically a free particle (described by $y(t)$) and a harmonic oscillator (described by $x(t)$) coupled in a simple way.

My question is if you guys know any system that could correspond to such a Lagrangian? Basically this is a free particle that is forced to oscillate by a harmonic oscillator that pulls it...

Comment: Is there a factor in front of the $xy$ term? Otherwise a problem with dimensions.

Comment: This is very similar to the Lagrange an of an electron in the beam of a free electron laser

Comment: Dimensionally its incorrect.

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: @jim I just encountered this Lagrangian in a course on path integration, where it was a toy model to solve analytically. It might be that in a physical system there can be a factor in front of it (depending on what units you use I guess ;-) )!

Comment: @Qmechanic you are right, the $\sigma$ can be seen as an uncertainty on the values of $x$ and $y$ (or inverse mass if you want, I edited it for you). But the coupling of the form $xy$ seemed somehow physical to me, that's why I posed the question. Now if you know any list applications, I'm willing to hear them :-). The course was on path integrals in economics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I guess that what you wrote is the Hamiltonian and not the Lagrangian  of the system and $\dot{x}$ stays for $p_x$ and $\dot{y}$ stays for $p_y$.

You can decouple the problem redefining $$(X,Y)^t = R(x,y)^t$$ for a suitable $R\in O(2)$ diagonalizing the symmetric matrix in the potential part of your Hamiltonian.  This way you see the final Hamiltonian is 
$$\left(\frac{p^2_X}{2m} + \lambda_+ X^2\right) + \left(\frac{p^2_Y}{2m} + \lambda_- Y^2\right)$$
where $\lambda_\pm$ are the eigenvalues of the above symmetric matrix.

In the considered case (up to the dimensional problem already stressed) you find that  $ \lambda_+ \lambda_-<0$ (because the determinant of the symmetric matrix is negative nomatter the sign in front of $xy$).

So you have a pair of 1D  non-mutually interacting particles, one subjected to a standard harmonic potential and the other subjected to a *repulsive* harmonic potential (like the one of centrifugal force for a constant angular speed).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For example, if the first particle is moving on a spring and its position sets the electric potential that controls the second, electrically charged, particle. This way you'd have the potential energy of the coupling in the form of the product of coordinates.